# How to make git branch name fullly showing? Zsh, with POWERLEVEL9K

Tags: zsh

[image]

I had shortened current path name. but I want to see whole git branch name. How can I do it?

My setting for .zshrc file

```
POWERLEVEL9K_LEFT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS=(time context dir vcs)
POWERLEVEL9K_RIGHT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS=(status rbenv)

POWERLEVEL9K_SHORTEN_DIR_LENGTH=1
POWERLEVEL9K_SHORTEN_STRATEGY=truncate_folders
POWERLEVEL9K_VCS_SHORTEN_STRATEGY=None
POWERLEVEL9K_SHORTEN_DELIMITER=".."
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open `~/.p10k.zsh` and find this:

```bsh
# If local branch name or tag is at most 32 characters long, show it in full.
# Otherwise show the first 12 … the last 12.
(( $#where > 32 )) && where[13,-13]="…"
```

Delete the last line to always show Git branch name in full without truncation.

Comment: In newer versions, this line might read like that:  
`# If local branch name is at most 32 characters long, show it in full.`  `# Otherwise show the first 12 … the last 12.`  `# Tip: To always show local branch name in full without truncation, delete the next line.`  `(( $#branch > 32 )) && branch[13,-13]="…"  # <-- this line`