# How to shorten directory names in git branches with Powerlevel10k?

Tags: zsh

I’m using the Powerlevel10k theme for ZSH and I’ve set `POWERLEVEL9K_SHORTEN_DIR_LENGTH=1` to shorten all directory names except for the current one. This works as expected: [`~/Desktop/Codes/OLED_Display/Codes` becomes `~/D/Co/O/Codes` ]

However, it doesn’t shorten directory names where a git branch starts.

For example, my prompt might look like this: `~/D/Co/O/git_branch_starts_here/Examples`, where `git_branch_starts_here` and `Examples` are colored blue while the rest are grey.

I want to achieve the following:

Shorten the git branch directories [or any anchors for that matter] too, so that it looks like this: `~/D/Co/O/g/Examples` Here, `g` and `Examples` should still be colored blue (indicating the start of a git branch) while the rest are grey as usual.

I tried reading through the .p10k.zsh file and I found these things;

```
  typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_SHORTEN_FOLDER_MARKER="(${(j:|:)anchor_files})"

  # If set to "first" ("last"), remove everything before the first (last) subdirectory that contains
  # files matching $POWERLEVEL9K_SHORTEN_FOLDER_MARKER. For example, when the current directory is
  # /foo/bar/git_repo/nested_git_repo/baz, prompt will display git_repo/nested_git_repo/baz (first)
  # or nested_git_repo/baz (last). This assumes that git_repo and nested_git_repo contain markers
  # and other directories don't.
  #
  # Optionally, "first" and "last" can be followed by ":<offset>" where <offset> is an integer.
  # This moves the truncation point to the right (positive offset) or to the left (negative offset)
  # relative to the marker. Plain "first" and "last" are equivalent to "first:0" and "last:0"

  typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_DIR_TRUNCATE_BEFORE_MARKER=false

  # Don't shorten this many last directory segments. They are anchors.
```

I don't understand what exactly they mean, but I tried messing around with them, but I can't seem to get what I want... Any help would be much appreciated :)

Edit: Tried changing `typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_SHORTEN_FOLDER_MARKER="(${(j:|:)anchor_files})"`  to `typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_SHORTEN_FOLDER_MARKER=""` and it did work in shortening the git branches, however I believe it completely removes the ability to determine whether something is an anchor or not? So not a good approach I suppose...

Edit 2: The links mentioned by @harrymc does not answer my question:

The [first link's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1734973/shorten-directory-name-on-powerlevel10k) completely truncates the directories to just the latest one: ie: `~/Documents/Repositories/cool-project $` becomes `~ cool-project $`

The [second link's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1540006/how-to-make-git-branch-name-fullly-showing-zsh-with-powerlevel9k) is the complete opposite of what I want to achieve. Deleting the line mentioned always presents the git branches completely... However, I did try messing with the values of `(( $#where > 32 )) && where[13,-13]="…"` but I do not notice any changes after sourcing `.p10k.zsh`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shorten directory name on Powerlevel10k](https://superuser.com/questions/1734973/shorten-directory-name-on-powerlevel10k). Also see [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1540006/how-to-make-git-branch-name-fullly-showing-zsh-with-powerlevel9k).

Comment: Nope. The first link's answer completely truncates the directories to just the latest one:
ie: `~/Documents/Repositories/cool-project $` becomes `~ cool-project $` 

The second link's answer is the complete opposite of what I want to achieve. Deleting the line mentioned always presents the git branches completely... However, I did try messing with the values of `(( $#where > 32 )) && where[13,-13]="…"` but I do not notice any changes after sourcing `.p10k.zsh`